# How to jump from 'form action' to view in pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm

I used PyCharm to write Django code. I write a form in a HTML file.

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" action="query" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="key_word" class="form-control" placeholder="查询条件">

                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-bg-red">
                        查询
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The action of the form is 'query'. And my urls.py is

```
url(r'^query/$', query.key_word_query, name='index')
```

But PyCharm throws an exception "Cannot resolve file 'query'" and "This inspection checks unresolved file references in HTML. ".
Why?
And could PyCharm jump to the matched view (query.key_word_query) by clicking the action 'query'?

Comment: Check the name of your url pattern.

Comment: you might also want to open a ticket in PyCharm bug tracker in case this is PyCharm bug

Comment: Don't raise a bug in pycharm . It probably doesn't create the right url you should be using the url template tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url contains a `/` (`query/`) whereas your action doesn't. So you *could* remove this slash but this isn't really the correct fix, you should be using the `url` template tag.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the perfect answer I want. So that I can use ⌘+click to jump to the matched url patterns.